# Android WebView disable keyboard for custom inputs

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I created a Web View application on Android. When user click a text input in the app it display the keyboard and user can type. But the problem is i don't want to display the keyboard when user click a text input with name datefilter. Because when user click this a date picker is open and when keyboard opens, keyboard going top on datepicker like this ;

[image]

and this is the html code of this input ;

```
<input type="text" name="datefilter" placeholder="Tarih Aralığı">
```

My opinion is write some js code like onFocusListener for this spesific input on Android. And after that execute a function when focus this and hide the keyboard ? But i don't know how to achieve this. Can someone help ?

Comment: The easy solution: By not setting the input as textfield. Or anything text related :)

Comment: Yes, that's true. But what if i don't have access to the website codes ?